# Presenting a View Controller after a UIPopoverController is dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios8, uipopovercontroller

I am having some difficulty presenting a full screen View Controller (specifically, an `MPMoviePlayerViewController`) immediately after dismissing a `UIPopoverController`. Essentially, I have a race condition and I'm not sure if there's an accepted best practice to correct it. Here is the code I started with:

```
   [[self searchPopoverController] dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

   MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[video videoURL]];
   [[player moviePlayer] setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
   [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
```

The problem is that the popover doesn't actually dismiss before the next lines of code are executed, resulting (as expected) in an "Attempt to present [a view controller] while a presentation is in progress" warning. Somewhat humorously, the video does start playing (you can hear the audio), but the view controller is not presented so you cannot see the video.

I've tried fixing this in several ways. The only reliable solution I have found is ugly and not a guaranteed fix:

```
   [[self searchPopoverController] dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

   dispatch_time_t start = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
   dispatch_after(start, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
      MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[video videoURL]];
      [[player moviePlayer] setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
      [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
   });
```

Since `UIPopoverController` does not inherit from `UIViewController`, I do not believe there is any method for dismissing the popover that includes a completion-handling block. I've tried using `NSInvocationOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`, with no success, for example:

```
   NSInvocationOperation *invokedOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(playVideo:) object:video];
   [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:invokedOperation];
```

There are lots of existing questions that touch on this issue, but most seem to revolve around dismissing a `UIViewController` or subclass, for which `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` is an obvious solution.

Comment: Can you use [[self searchPopoverController] dismissPopoverAnimated:NO] and wrap it in a block based UIViewAnimation with an onComplete handler?

Comment: Do you mean via `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:`? If so, I just tried that, but it produced the same error. The completion block still fires before the popover is _fully_ dismissed. My guess is that method believes that the animation block is complete because it was not designed to handle things like a popover dismissal. But if you meant something else, please clarify for me.

Comment: I mean manually fade it out in `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` and then on completion call `[[self searchPopoverController] dismissPopoverAnimated:NO]` and the rest of your code.

Comment: I don't think it's the animation that's the problem, per se. For example, even if I change it to `[[self searchPopoverController] dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];`, the issue persists. It would seem to me that animating the dismissal of the popover controller myself would be an inordinate amount of work, since it doesn't inherit from `UIView`. But I'll explore this option.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the popover delegate method `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover`

This will notify you once the pop over has fully been dismissed.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPopoverControllerDelegate/popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work. That delegate method is not called in response to programmatic dismissal of a `UIPopoverController`—only to automatic dismissals triggered by tapping outside of the popover controller.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you implement the UIPopoverControllerDelegate protocol and add your controller as delegate, then you can fire the second viewController off from

```
-(void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:
```

Comment: Because of this, from the documentation on `UIPopoverControllerDelegate`: "The popover controller does not call this method in response to programmatic calls to the dismissPopoverAnimated: method. If you dismiss the popover programmatically, you should perform any cleanup actions immediately after calling the dismissPopoverAnimated: method."

Comment: I think an argument could be made that any dismissal of the popover should indeed call that delegate method, but I'm sure Apple has their reasons. Given that, however, I'm not sure why the programmatic dismissal method `dismissPopoverAnimated:` does not have a completion block option.